# How to view the JSON directly through Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have this url:

http://localhost:8080/flow/getFlow?flowName=3TCs

This returns a json array from my Spring Controller.

But when I try to visualize it using Chrome I receive the following response:

> HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed 
>   Message Request method 'GET' not supported

Is there a way to view the json making a post request directly through the chrome?

Comment: I'd recommend [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for that kind of thing

Comment: you have created POST request in controller

Comment: Yeah I dont understand either. I have all post but I need to make a get url to make this work. `$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/flow/getFlow?flowName=' + flowName,`

Comment: @ChrisSatchell postman is an option but not a direct request :)

Comment: @BarrJ True, that's why I only chimed in with a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is no.

When you try to view the JSON directly from chrome you issue a get request, if the api does not accept get requests to the specific method you will not be able to view the result.

This is usually do to security requirements in the server side. 
You have to check which request the api accepts and send it accordingly, usually you will have to send a post request.

It will block any attempt for get.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response from the AJAX, write this line:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(myJSON).
```

For example, we have this JSON array in JavaScript:

```
var obj = { "name":"kaleemullah", "email":"kaleemrao9@gmail.com", "city":"Lahore"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(myJSON)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check data sent in post request in **Network** tab in chrome.
Check this image for more info.
[Chrome Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viZMv.png)